# How can I iterate on a JsArray using Play JSON avoiding case classes?

Tags: play-json

Here's my use case: I need to access to an Array in a JSON document and then iterate on it in order to apply JSON coast-to-coast transformation to each object and get a collection of the transformed object.

I was thinking about an approach like this:

```
def myTransformerFunc(json: JsValue): JsResult[JsObject] = {}

val results = (res.json \ "results")  // access to the the array
val transformedObjects = results.map( myTransformerFunc(_) )
```

But `results` is a `JsLookupResult` type and has no `.map()` method.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 val results = (res.json \ "results").as[String]
```